# The answer to life, the universe, and everything

Tags: popularity-contest

**Introduction**: Deep Thought calculated *The answer to life the universe and everything* in a period of 7.5 million years, the solution was **`42`**.

Write a program in any programming language that takes approx `75` seconds to calculate, starting from whatever you want, and output the number **`42`**.

N.B. The number `42` must be calculated somehow (random numbers, whatever you prefer), not just hard-coded in your script.

As suggested, you can't use `sleep` or equivalent functions. Be inventive.

Comment: You should probably ban sleep and time functions, or else the solution will just be sleep(75);print 41+1

Comment: This might better serve as a popularity contest to see what ways people can creatively come up with an answer rather than variations of `sleep(75);print("%d\n",41+1);`

Comment: @tecywiz121 you beat me to it!

Comment: To calculate takes approx 75 seconds? But computer chips are so varied... How can this be possible - it might take 75 seconds on my machine, but the next computer might monster it in 7.5 seconds...

Comment: Without `sleep` available the answers are going to be very hardware dependent I imagine...what takes 75s on your machine will probably take 750s on my machine :P

Comment: @Fozzedout the entire script must run in 75 seconds

Comment: @Josh Not true; for example, Java has `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @Josh Agreed, this should be popularity contest. As it stands there's nothing particularly interesting about this that makes it a code golf. Not to mention that the rules aren't even particularly well defined. The only real way to guarantee time is to use some form of timer. I might be inclined to close vote

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, if needed I can change it to a popularity contest. **edit** changed.

Comment: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now. This seems like the best alternative to using sleep-like libraries of your language. All this takes is a few http requests.

Comment: I accidentally made mine take 10 minutes! :O

Comment: I have found ways to generate 42 in a funny way, but they took much much more than 75s. Making a algorithm that take approx. 75 sec is really hard.

Comment: if it takes 7.5 milion years I think it could be accepted as answer :P

Comment: Well, darn.  The time thing makes the most interesting solution too simple:  If we define `a=0, b=1,...z=25`, then you can sum `"earth"` (and subtract `length("earth")` due to it not finishing the calculation) to get 42...

Comment: The answer to Life, the Universe, and everything = `2**5+0x15f%11`

Comment: Proud to be the 42nd upvote on this question :)

Comment: The votes on this are so almost perfect... *is tempted to downvote to get the vote count back to 42*

Comment: @Doorknob I downvoted becuase 1) it's an off-topic question and 2) I'm getting the vote count back to 42.

Answer (score 54):

This takes about 75s on a raspberry pi overclocked to 1GHz

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import product, count

for n in count(1):
    i = 0
    for a, b, c, d in product(range(n), repeat=4):
        if a > b > c > d > 0 == (a*b-c*d)%n == (a*c-b*d)%n == (a*d-b*c)%n:
            i += 1
    if i == n:
        break
print i
```

It works because:

> 42 is the only known value that is the number of sets of four
>   distinct positive integers a,b,c,d, each less than the value itself,
>   such that ab-cd, ac-bd, and ad-bc are each multiples of the value.
>   Whether there are other values remains an open question

http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath255.htm

Comment: So you'll either find a new number that satisfies this equation or you'll print 42 :)

Comment: It didn't print anything on my pc

Comment: @FezVrasta, because the last line went missing. doh!

Comment: Wow! Perfect math rebus and the overclocking thing... ha ha ha +1!

Comment: I just had to upvote this answer from 41 to 42..

Comment: I upvoted your question to 42. I hope it stays at that number ^^

Comment: it's funny that this answer has a hard cap score of 42 (not upvoting)

Comment: I really want to upvote this because of the overlocked raspberry pi, but I just can't given it's current score. I have a bad feeling we're going to have a tie

Answer (score 42):

### Python 2.7

To answer the question, one must *know* the question - and the question is:

> What do you get when you multiply six by nine? <sup>Thanks to TRiG for the correction</sup>

So **Deep Thought** relies on the [handy use of base 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42):

> 6<sub>13</sub> x 9<sub>13</sub> = 42<sub>13</sub>

We import our constants:

```
from random import randrange as scrabbleBag, randint
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
life,universe,everything,nothing=6,9,1,-3
endOfTheUniverse = 80
```

We also define our earth-things, being a **bag of scrabble tiles**, **Arthur** (a predictable albeit it slightly odd, computer of sorts), **Trillian** (our rational heroine),

```
tile = lambda i: scrabbleBag(26)
arthur = lambda i: int(`i`,life+universe+everything+nothing)
trillian = lambda i: ''.join(map(str,divmod(i,life+universe+everything+nothing)))
```

We introduce **Zaphod** - a random sort, who eventually runs out of steam as we near the `endOfTheUniverse`.

```
zaphod = lambda : not(randint(0,(endOfTheUniverse-(datetime.now() - start).seconds)**3))
```

And **Marvin the Paranoid Android**, whose positive attitude could stop any party:

```
marvin = lambda : endOfTheUniverse<(datetime.now() - start).seconds
```

And we continue to run these 4 characters through the mix until they compute ***it***:

```
while answer is not life * universe * everything:
  rack = sum(tile(i) for i in range(7))
  answer = (zaphod or marvin) and arthur(rack)
print trillian(answer)
```

### The complete `deepthought.py`:

```
from random import randrange as scrabbleBag, randint
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
life,universe,everything,nothing=6,9,1,-3
endOfTheUniverse = 80

tile = lambda i: scrabbleBag(26)
arthur = lambda i: int(`i`,life+universe+everything+nothing)
trillian = lambda i: ''.join(map(str,divmod(i,life+universe+everything+nothing)))

start = datetime.now()

zaphod = lambda: not(randint(0,(endOfTheUniverse-(datetime.now() - start).seconds)**3))
marvin = lambda: endOfTheUniverse<(datetime.now() - start).seconds

answer = None
while answer is not life * universe * everything:
  rack = sum(tile(i) for i in range(7))
  answer = (zaphod() or marvin()) and arthur(rack)
print trillian(answer)
```

This should finish somewhere around the 75 second mark, definitely finishing by 80 seconds. Sometimes earlier to to Zaphods *Infinite Improbability Drive*.

Comment: the answer is great but if I run it on 2.7.2 it throws an error `File "main.py", line 13, in 
    zaphod = not(randint(i,(80-(datetime.now() - start).seconds)**3))
NameError: name 'i' is not defined` :(

Comment: @FezVrasta Sorry, I accidentally added some wrong code. Fixed it now, should work.

Comment: awesome, it works :) now we need a bigger computer to compute the question!

Comment: "I may be a sorry case, but I don't write jokes in base-13." - DNA

Comment: No, the question, as generated by scrabble tiles on the original radio series, was *What do you get when you multiply six by nine?*

Comment: It is the ultimate question after all; best not to misquote! :)

Comment: Actually Deep Thought didn't know the ultimate question, and by the way the Ultimate question was not that one, that was just a guess stated by Arthur :P **But I guess this is not the right place to talk about this**

Comment: @TRiG fixed now!

Comment: This is now sitting at 42 votes. Do I want more votes, or do I want the coolest possible score for this question?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr no, this answer needs to be locked in as it stands right now. No more rep for you.

Answer (score 13):

## DOS Batch — the answer to life, the Universe and everything

Thanks to mynameiscoffey for his simplification!

Save as `answer.bat`:

```
@ ping 127.0.0.1 -n 76 >nul && @ echo %~z0
```

Then run it, and wait 75 seconds:

```
> answer
42
```

Comment: Looks like your **Deep Thought** has a different idea, it returns me **40** :P

Comment: I've used Notepad++, I've a Windows 8 x64

Comment: No luck even with NotePad, the version with the exclamation mark instead works

Comment: Cool, can you guess how it works?

Comment: Ehm no clues sorry

Comment: Why would your first example ever produce 42? The code is only 40 bytes, including the newline. Unless you had some extra characters in there (maybe a newline at the end) it should always produce 40.

Comment: Also, with your second example, you could change it to `@<space><space>echo %~z0`, so that the output is "42", and not "42!".

Comment: @YiminRong, The carriage return character for NotePad is always two bytes.

Comment: @unclemeat - are you terminating the last line with a carriage return?

Comment: Of course not, if I did that I would get the answer 42, but that isn't included in your answer.

Comment: Notepad++ and wordpad won't effect the answer I've submitted as an edit.

Comment: Notepad++ and Wordpad weren't the problem - their newline characters are both 2 bytes as well.

Comment: @YiminRong, the spaces are quite obvious. Anyone who will test out your answer will copy / paste the code exactly as it appears.

Comment: why not just make it one line to avoid the messy CRLF issue, `@ ping 127.0.0.1 -n 76 >nul && @ echo %~z0`, using ` && ` instead of relying on a pair of CRLF

Comment: @mynameiscoffey - thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: ping is well known as a sleep equivalent in batch files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file for instance.

Comment: @BrianMinton - I would consider it relying on a side effect. `ping` is not meant to be a sleep function. Otherwise, resource kits wouldn't see the need to provide an actual `sleep` function.

Answer (score 11):

## Bash (OS X)

This could probably be ported to other systems without too much trouble. Replace `say` with whatever you're using as a text-to-speech command line utility. The `-f` option takes input from a named file.

With a bit of luck, it might even output the correct number :-)

This takes almost exactly 1 minute 15 seconds to run on my system (OS X 10.5).

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -E '^life|universe|and.everything|[ultimate]question$' /usr/share/dict/words | sed 's/$/,/' | nl > "$TMPDIR/deepthought"
say -v Alex -f "$TMPDIR/deepthought"
nw=`cat $TMPDIR/deepthought | wc -l`
say -v Alex "The answer, to the ultimate question, is: $nw"
echo $nw
rm "$TMPDIR/deepthought"
```

Answer (score 10):

### MATLAB

This is a tough one. Since we do not really know the question, the only viable method of getting the answer is by means of a global optimisation method. In this case I opted for the [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) method, since this one has given me nice answers to tough questions before.

All this code is doing is looking for the optimal value of a function which input is life itself. And the amazing thing is that it works. So, did I just validate Deep Thought?

```
tic;

the_answer=round(simulannealbnd(@(life)abs(3.7376696-log(life)),140489, ...
           -inf,inf,saoptimset('MaxFunEvals',10^16)))
toc;
```

Output:

```
the_answer =

    42

Elapsed time is 74.892428 seconds.
```

Answer (score 5):

## C - 1089 bytes

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int answer(int the)
{
   int to = 0;

   while (the != 0) {
      to *= 10;
      to += the%10;
      the /= 10;
   }
   return to;
}

int optimism(int the)
{
    return abs(the);
}

int getRandomNumber()
{
    return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll.
              // guaranteed to be random.
}

int main()
{
    // initialize
    int life = getRandomNumber(), universe, everything;

    // get inverse answer
    int question = clock();
    while (clock()-question < CLOCKS_PER_SEC*75) {
        life += getRandomNumber();
    }
    life = optimism(life); // optimism is the best way to see life
    life %= 1000;

    // avoids unwanted race conditions with the answer by "Lego Stormtroopr"
    if (life<100 || life>997) {life -= getRandomNumber()*100;}
    if (optimism(life/100%10 - life%10) < 2) {life += getRandomNumber();}
    universe = answer(life);
    everything = optimism(life<universe?life-universe:universe-life);

    printf("%d\n", (answer(everything)+everything+3)/26);

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Compressed:

```
#include <time.h>

int f(int d) {
   int e = 0;
   while (d != 0) e = e*10+d%10, d /= 10;
   return e;
}

int main() {
    int a = 4, b, c, d = clock();
    while (clock()-d < CLOCKS_PER_SEC*75) a += 4;
    a = abs(a)%1000;
    a -= a<100||a>997?400:0;
    a += abs(a/100%10-a%10)<2?4:0;
    b = f(a);
    c = abs(a<b?a-b:b-a);
    return (f(c)+c+3)/26;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int i, j;

int main() {
    i = clock();
    while(clock() - i < 75 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    for(i = j = 0 ; i < 48 ; i++)
        j += "The answer to Life, the Universe, and everything"[i];
    printf("%i", j % 157);
}
```

Comment: while-looping until `clock()` exceeds some value seems to violate the `no sleep()` rule, since that's basically a cpu-intensive sleep

Comment: popularity-contest.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre It was [tag:code-golf] when I submitted the answer. Anyways, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby

```
t = Time.new.to_i
n = 0
loop{
  break if Random.new(n).rand(2000000) == Random.new(374076).rand(1000000)
  n += 1
}
puts Random.new(n).rand(2000000)
puts "Took #{Time.new.to_i - t} seconds; seed was #{n}"
```

Output on my machine:

```
42
Took 123 seconds; seed was 3771996
```

This abuses the RNG. ;)

Comment: How do you ensure it lasts 75 seconds?

Comment: @Arlaud It runs through 3.7 million iterations of a loop whIch generates 2 random numbers per iteration! Technically if you had some supercomputer it could be faster, but for any reasonable hardware it would take at least 75 secs, and I don't want to be boring and use sleep or time methods.

Comment: Update: ... well now it prints `Took 25 seconds; seed was 3771996` on my average-performance laptop. So, uhh... I lied. :P

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript - Finding "the answer to life and everything" by solving an equation

Let's have a look at this equation :

```
1 / p  +  1 / q  +  1 / r  =  1 / 2
```

There is many solutions, but if you want `r` to be as big as possible and `p`, `q` and `r` to be naturals there is only two solutions :

`1/3 + 1/7 + 1/42 = 1/2` and `1/7 + 1/3 + 1/42 = 1/2`

with `p <= q <= r`, there is only one solution and `r` always equal to `42`

What is the most (in)efficient way to solve a equation ?

By trying all possibles values !

Here is the code :

```
var n = Math.pow(2, 32); 
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)  
{ 
    for (var j = 1; j <= n;  j++)
    {
        for (var k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            if ((1 / i + 1 / j + 1 / k) == 1 / 2)                
               throw k;                
        }
    }
}
```

How much time will it take ? To be honest, I do not know because I have not been able to run it to the end.

However, you can try with small  `n` values (it has to be bigger or equal to `42`) and you will get correct result. For small values such as `n = 2000`, it takes almost one minute on my laptop. So i guess with big values given in the example it will take days, weeks, or even years !!!

**Finding the solution in approximately 75 seconds :**

One requirement from initial question is it should take approximately 75 sec to execute. One way to achieve this is to  automatically adjust the complexity of the algorithm over the time :

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var iterations = 0; 
var n = Math.pow(2, 32); 
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        for (var k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            if ((1 / i + 1 / j + 1 / k) == 1 / 2)               
                throw k;
            
            if (new Date().getTime() - now > 1000) //one second has elapsed
            {
                now *= 2; //never wanna see you again
                n = 42;   //this is the minimum               
                while(3 * n * n + 7 * n + 42 < iterations * 74) n++;
                i = j = k = 0; //reset
            }
            iterations++;
        }
    }
}
```

How it works (for the curious) : it checks how many iterations have been done in one second, then multiply this by 74 and adjust `n` to match that value. eg : if it take one second to do 500 iterations, it will take 10 seconds to do 5000 iterations. Note that it multiply by 74 not 75 because we already spent one second for "benchmarking".

[source and credits for math](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/42.html)

Answer (score 2):

C# - 151 Characters

```
class P
{
   static void Main()
   {
      var w = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
      w.Start();
      while (w.ElapsedMilliseconds < 75000);
      System.Console.Write((int)'*');
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this not equivalent to thread sleep?

Comment: Of course it is not equivalent to thread sleep. Thread sleep makes main thread inactive for specified amount of time. This program does not make main thread inactive. It involves main thread to compare elapsed time. And when that specified amount of time (75s) is elapsed, it prints the output.

Comment: I know <i>functionally</i> it is not the same, but follows the same premise. The OP wanted it to be creative and not have the the language wait 75 seconds - which is what this is doing.

Comment: To me this solution is as good/bad as the solution for DOS.  The DOS solution is keeping the program busy by pinging, and this one is keeping itself busy by comparing the time elapsed.  I don't see any difference.  If that can get many upvotes so this one should also get.  By the way, ping command does a 'sleep' internally.

Answer (score 2):

**C++**

Calculates the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of [10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partition%2010) via a rather inefficient method. Took 130s to run in a Release build on my system but someone with a sufficiently fast PC should be able to run it in ~75s...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool NextPermutationWithRepetition(vector<int>& perm, int n) {
    int carry = 1;
    auto it = begin(perm);
    while (it != end(perm) && carry) {
        ++*it;
        carry = (*it - 1) / n;
        *it = ((*it - 1) % n) + 1;
        ++it;
    }
    if (carry) {
        if (perm.size() == n) return false;
        perm.push_back(carry);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> perm;
    set<vector<int>> uniquePartitions;
    const int n = 10;
    while (NextPermutationWithRepetition(perm, n)) {
        if (accumulate(begin(perm), end(perm), 0) == n)  {
            auto sortedPerm = perm;
            sort(begin(sortedPerm), end(sortedPerm));
            uniquePartitions.insert(sortedPerm);
        }
    }
    cout << uniquePartitions.size() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript

This will take a while to alert something ... but it's worth since it will show you The answer to life the universe and everything!

```
var x = 0, b = document.body.children[0];
var theAnswer = function(){
  b.textContent = ++x;
  if(x == 125774) alert(Math.pow(x, 1/Math.PI)).toFixed(0);  
  else setTimeout(theAnswer);
};
theAnswer();
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/HKurF)

Comment: Much much more than 75 seconds...

Comment: but it's tottaly worth!

Answer (score 2):

### Assembly (linked by gcc)

On a sufficiently slow computer (CPU speed ~2Hz) this should take around 75 seconds to run:

```
  .globl        main
main:
  movl  $52, %edx
  movl  $0, %edi
l4:
  addl $1, %edi
  cmp %edx, %edi
  jl l4
  call  putchar
  movl  $50, %edx
  movl  $0, %edi
l2:
  addl $1, %edi
  cmp %edx, %edi
  jl l2
  call  putchar
  movl  $10, %edx
  movl  $0, %edi
ln:
  addl $1, %edi
  cmp %edx, %edi
  jl ln
  call  putchar
  ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python

Sometimes an answer is only clear at the very end of a calculation, but aspects of it are visible before termination.

And little known is the sequence of inputs Deep Thought was seeded with:

271, 329, 322, 488, 79, 15, 60, 1, 9

Hence:

```
from datetime import datetime
n = datetime.now
o = n().second

def bs(x,n,t,f):
    return ([t]+bs(x-2**(n-1),n-1,t,f) if x>=2**(n-1) else [f]+bs(x,n-1,t,f)) if n>0 else []

u = [271,329,322,488,79,15,60,1,9,'#',' ','',]
for i, g in enumerate(u[:5]):
    while n().second!=(o+(i+u[7])*u[5])%u[6]:
        pass # the dice
    print u[11].join(bs(g,*u[8:11]))
```

Et voila - the answer is provided after 75 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash and Linux utils:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(uname) == "Linux" ]; then
    : $(arecord -q | head -c 600000)
    man -s4 random | head -n1 | tr -d ' ' | wc -c
else
    echo "Deep Thought didn't run $(uname)"
fi
```

Deep Thought is listening carefully all the way through the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

## Java (227 characters)

Who says that bitwise manipulations are not fun? Or that java can't be confusing?
We loop for 75 seconds and then boom the answer.

```
public class T{public static void main(String[]b){long d=(1<<16^1<<13^1<<10^31<<3);long t=System.currentTimeMillis();long e=t+d;for(;e>System.currentTimeMillis();){}d=d%((((d&~(1<<16))>>7)^(1<<4))^1<<2);System.out.println(d);}}
```

Ungolfed

```
public class T
{
    public static void main(String[] b)
    {
        long d = (1 << 16 ^ 1 << 13 ^ 1 << 10 ^ 31 << 3);
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long e = t + d;
        for (; e > System.currentTimeMillis();){}
        d = d % ((((d & ~(1 << 16)) >> 7) ^ (1 << 4)) ^ 1 << 2);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PureBasic

In keeping with the fact that different hardware will produce different results, there is no fixed answer for this. I am using an elapsed time function so I know when to stop calculating.

Basically, it will calculate the largest two prime numbers when subtracted is 42

Faster your machine, the larger the primes will be :-)

```
OpenConsole()

sw = ElapsedMilliseconds()
FoundFigure1 = 0
FoundFigure2 = 0

PreviousPrime = 1

For i = 3 To 10000000000 Step 2
  PrimeFound = #True
  For j = 2 To i-1
    If i % j = 0
      PrimeFound = #False
      Break
    EndIf
  Next
  If PrimeFound = #True
    If i - PreviousPrime = 41+1
      FoundFigure1 = PreviousPrime
      FoundFigure2 = i
    EndIf

    PreviousPrime = i
  EndIf

  If ElapsedMilliseconds() - sw > 75000
    Break
  EndIf
Next

Print("Answer: ")
Print(Str(FoundFigure2 - FoundFigure1))
Input()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby

> A program to add (0.56) power n for 75 times. Value of `n is 1`
>
> Where `n=1` should be obtained from any form of `Time diffrence`

```
def solve
  a=0.56
  i=0
  t1=Time.now
  while(i < 75)
        t1 = Time.now
        while((b=Time.now-t1) < 1.0)
        end
        a += 0.56 ** b.to_i
        i += 1
  end
  a.to_i
end

puts solve
```

Using ruby time difference I've verified the execution time which is approx `75.014267762`

Answer (score 0):

***MeatSpace***

Pace off a distance which takes approximately 70/4 seconds for your `servant^H^H^H^Hcomputer` (it could be human, dog, or anything that can pick up numeral tiles) to walk.  Place a large numeral `4` and a large numeral `2` there.  Place your `computer` to the output point.  Start the timer, have it walk to the numeral depot and bring back one number at a time.

I allocated 5 seconds to pick them up and put them down.

Answer (score 0):

**Another C# Example**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FourtyTwo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime then = DateTime.Now;
            Thread.Sleep(42000);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan t = now - then;
            Console.WriteLine(t.Seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using "sleep"

Comment: oops, read it as can use sleep -10 for me!

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(80);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 80);
//$start=time();
$count=0;
do{
$rand=rand(0,(75000000/40+2));  
$rand=rand(0,$rand);
    if(($rand==42 || $rand==75-42 || $rand== floor(75/42)) && (!rand(0,(4*2)))
      ){
      $count++;
    }
}while($count!=42);
echo $count;
//echo '<br>elapsed time is '.(time()-$start);
?>
```

This is as close as I'm getting tonight. Running it at [tecbrat.com](http://www.tecbrat.com/test1.php), an old IBM NetVista P4 running Ubuntu 10.04, showed 69 seconds and 78 seconds on my last 2 runs.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (Bitwise obfuscation) (not bad for 136 bytes!)

It may be seen as a bit on the cheaty side, but the functions were meticulously thought out, bearing in mind that the 75000ms value would be calculated prior to the functions used to calculate 42. It's quite poetic when you look at it, really :)

`setTimeout("alert($=((_=_=>(_<<-~-~[])|-~[])(_(-~[])))<<-~[])",($=$=>$<<-~-~-~[]|-~[])((_=_=>_<<-~[]|-~[])(_(_(_($($($(-~[]))))))))^-~[])`

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error... `Unexpected token >`

Comment: I have this working on Firefox 26.0 which accepts the x=x=>f(x) notation... What version are you running this on?

Comment: i'm running chrome 31 on windows 7 ...

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Ah, sadly fat arrow notation used to define the two functions in each of the statements only works for Firefox 22 and above...

Comment: i'm almost crying ... your solution is indeed beautyful!

Answer (score 0):

I am not too good with this kind of stuff.  I'm an app developer but I've never had any training in C and I mostly make apps that grab stuff from servers and make the information look pretty...

I have no idea if this will work and there's a bit of extra code in there because it's in a iphone app and I display a progress hud and an alert view when 42 has been reached:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MBProgressHUD * hud;

-(IBAction)answer:(id)sender;

@end

int number;
int initialCounter;

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize hud;

-(IBAction)answer:(id)sender
{
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Calculating";

    [self calculate];

    number = arc4random();
}

-(void)calculate
{

    int random = arc4random();

    if (number == 42){
        hud.hidden = YES;
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete!"
                                                          message:@"The answer is 42."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [message show];
    }

    else if(number<42){
        number = number + random;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self calculate];
        });
    }

    else if(number>42){
        number = number - random;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self calculate];
        });
    }
}

@end
```