# number of answers and comments

Tags: code-golf, internet

Write a software that prints on stdout the number of answers and the number of comments(visible and collapsed of question and answers) of this question/page.

Your script must run with this page closed when it starts.

Expected example output:

```
A12C40
```

Where A stands for Answers and C for Comments.

Comment: Little comment to check something, if you dont mind ;)

Comment: Comments on the question only or all comments on the page?

Comment: All the comments

Comment: Does the code have to handle the case when the comments are collapsed when there are too many? And there is also the case when there are too many answers (though I doubt it will get that many).

Comment: (does someone have a link of a multi-page question? lol)

Comment: @FezVrasta: [Here's one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code), but that's just making it tedious.

Comment: How long until someone writes a program that read the most upvoted answer here, and run it ? :D

Comment: Is this a clever scheme to get the most viewed question through people testing their scripts?

Comment: For testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Is it allowed for the script to add/delete comments itself?

Comment: Is it possible to break any of these scripts with cleverly crafted comments? I haven't the time to try it at the moment.

Comment: Lot of people have tried to break them, lot of scripts was then broken and lot of them was fixed to work again ^_^

Answer (score 18):

## Perl, <strike>91 96</strike>  92 chars

```
$_=`curl -sL qr.net/_9`;s/<[^>]+nt="(.+)/$c+=$1/ge;say"A",s/<td.*"ans//g,C,$c+s/<tr.*"com//g
```

---

Some stuff just to break solutions of others ha ha ha :-P

show **93** more comments

href

nt="99" (ha ha crash @Fez Vrasta)

a
,show **99**show **99** ha ha

[href](http://bit.ly/answercell)
[href](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20277/answercell)
[href](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20277/comment)
ha ha haha :-D

jeeez, just broke my own answer! I discovered that one of the above tricks, which I thought does nothing, will start working *after* this answer is not edited for some time! So your solutions will work only for some time. That's why you had seen +1 more answer in your solutions..  It's a timed bomb! My answer is already prone to it :-) Aaah, found a way how to launch it NOW...

Comment: In the interest of breaking a few more scripts that use css selectors, perhaps a <a href="" class="comment>comment link</a> might work?

Comment: Denis unfortunatelly SE will not allow you to display this. You can test on your own answer :)

Comment: I check for > so it's not breakable

Comment: @FezVrasta ermm.. not breakable? Then how is it possible than I broke it? ;)

Comment: @Tomas good, now I do see a proper output with `perl -E`. Deleting my comment. Also you can delete your reference to my answer, as you are not broking it any more :)

Comment: @Tomas should be fixed now

Answer (score 9):

#### XQuery, <strike>169</strike>, <strike>160</strike>, 165

```
let$d:=html:parse(fetch:binary('http://qr.net/1_'))return"A"||count($d//*[@class="answer"])||"C"||count($d//*[@class="comment"])+sum($d//*[@class="comments-link"]/b)
```

More readable (with spaces):

```
let $d:= html:parse(fetch:binary('http://qr.net/1_'))
return "A" || count($d//*[@class="answer"]) || "C" || count($d//*[@class="comment"]) + sum($d//*[@class="comments-link"]/b)
```

[BaseX](http://basex.org) was used as XQuery processor.

Comment: Would be even shorter (by using the `doc()` function) if this page would be valid XML...

Comment: And this seems to be the first answer ever on code-golf using XQuery... turns out to be quite suitable :)

Comment: on this site I discover a new language every day, this one is quite interesting, thanks. Does it count hidden comments?

Comment: @FezVrasta Yeah, and XQuery isn't even esoteric :) Yes it does, thats what `$d//*[@class="comments-link"]/b` is for (in the <b> tag the number of hidden comments is shown)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 180

```
import lxml.html as h
s=h.parse('http://qr.net/1_').find('body').cssselect
print('A',len(s('.answer')),'C',len(s('.comment'))+sum(int(e.text)for e in s('.comments-link b')),sep='')
```

I'm assuming that this question won't have multiple pages of answers.

Comment: blender: no luck even with block code :P

Comment: @FezVrasta: I'm getting `A13C20`. Include an angled bracket in the regex and I think it should be good, as those are escaped.

Comment: Yes I've already did it. thanks

Comment: Hmmm... "Ignore this stuff" huh? What happens if someone edits that out of the answer, then?

Comment: Invalid syntax. `,sep=''`

Comment: @Sukminder: It's Python 3.

Comment: Ah, yes. Should perhaps have seen / deducted that. Now I only have to get rid of 5 bytes in my answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

### BASH + AWK <s>163</s>, <s>144</s>, <s>138</s>, <s>111</s>, <s>110</s>, <s>114</s>, <s>131</s>, <s>132</s>, 105

```
curl -sL http://qr.net/_9|awk -F'[<>]' '/^[\t]*>s/{c+=$4}/<tr.*"c/{++c}/<t.*"a/{++a}END{print "A"a"C"c}'
```

Which is the same as this, but without redirecting to a file:

```
curl -sL http://qr.net/_9>f
awk -F'[<>]' '/^[\t]*>s/{c+=$4}/<tr.*"c/{++c}/<t.*"a/{++a}END{print "A"a"C"c}' f
```

#### Current output

```
A16C76
```

#### Explanation

curl

Transfer a URL.

- `-s` in `curl` is for silent. And `-L` to follow redirects.

awk

To parse the file. As some answers had some code to break other answers, the parsing has been changed so that it parses from the beginning of the line `(^`) to make sure it is not broken.

- `-F'[<>]'` set field separators as `<` or `>`. This way the text can be parsed properly for the "show XXX more comments".
- `/^[\t]*>show <b>/{c+=$4}` on lines containing "spaces....>show", get the 4th field (based on `<`, `>` separators) and add the value to the comments counter.
- `/^[ ]*<tr.*s="comm/{++c}` on lines containing "spaces...

  `/^<td.*rcell">/{++a}` on lines containing "", increment the counter of answers.

  `END{print "A"a"C"c}` print the output.

Comment: so it does not count the collapsed comments?

Comment: i think you mixed `m` and `f` in your code: `echo "A$(grep -c 'rcell">' m)C$(grep -c 'mment">' f)"` should be `echo "A$(grep -c 'rcell">' f)C$(grep -c 'mment">' f)"`, no?

Comment: @plannapus yes, error from copy paste. Solved, thanks!

Comment: @FezVrasta mmm no, now it is returning `A6C19` which is apparently fine.

Comment: no, there is 1 collapsed comment that your script doesn't count

Comment: Well @FezVrasta what I see is that the collapsed comments are not in the HTML, they just get fetched when clicking on "add / show X comments".

Comment: Yes exactly but other solutions count them as well, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: @FezVrasta ook now I see. Just updated accordingly. 163 chars.

Comment: @FezVrasta check updated code, with less characters. I messed with the file name. We can save some chars by making the `$( aaa )` be `$(aaa)` but by now I prefer a expanded version for readibilty sake.

Comment: Just tested your code, and it reports "A14C159", which I believe is not quite correct.

Comment: Well @Abhijit it happens that people keep updating their posts to break the conditions in the rest o f the answers... And I cannot keep updating my answer every time someone update his :D

Comment: OK, now you seem to have a correct solution, finally:-P Gave you a hard time, right? :-) A lot of fixing and +22 chars.. :) You may save 3 by using a pipe: `curl -sL http://qr.net/_9|awk...`

Comment: qr.net shortcut is expired :(

Answer (score 5):

#### R, 326

```
library(XML);b=htmlParse("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20277");z=xpathApply;x=do.call(sum,sapply(z(b,"//tbody",xmlAttrs),function(x)as.integer(x[[1]])))+length(z(b,"//tr[@class='comment']",xmlValue));y=gsub("[^0-9]","",z(b,"//div[@class='subheader answers-subheader']/h2",xmlValue)[[1]]);cat("A",y,"C",x,sep="")
```

With indentation and explanations:

```r
library(XML)
b=htmlParse("https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20277")
z=xpathApply
x=do.call(sum,sapply(z(b,"//tbody",xmlAttrs),  #Take the first attribute of tag tbody
                     function(x)as.integer(x[[1]]))) #And sum them (=nb of hidden comments
  +length(z(b,"//tr[@class='comment']",xmlValue)) #+nb of visible comments
y=gsub("[^0-9]","", #This is more straightforward as the number of answers is given on front page.
        z(b,"//div[@class='subheader answers-subheader']/h2",xmlValue)[[1]])
cat("A",y,"C",x,sep="")
```

Tested with [this page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20034/the-answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything), it gives the right number of comments (including hidden) **on the front page** and the right number of answers, i. e. `A23C63`.

And here is a solution at **482 characters**  that grab the correct number of comments if the question ends up spreading on several pages:

```
library(XML);h=htmlParse;z=xpathApply;v=xmlValue;a=xmlAttrs;s=sapply;c="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com";f=function(b,i){do.call(sum,s(z(b,"//tbody",a)[i],function(x)as.integer(x[[1]])))+length(z(b,"//tr[@class='comment']",v))};b=h(paste0(c,"/questions/20277"));x=f(b);u=unique(s(z(b,"//div[@class='pager-answers']/a",a),`[`,1));if(length(u))x=x+sum(s(u,function(x)f(h(paste0(c,x)),-1)));y=gsub("[^0-9]","",z(b,"//div[@id='answers-header']/div/h2",v)[[1]]);cat("A",y,"C",x,sep="")
```

Indented:

```r
library(XML)
h=htmlParse
z=xpathApply
v=xmlValue
a=xmlAttrs
s=sapply
c="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com"
f=function(b,i){do.call(sum,s(z(b,"//tbody",a)[i],function(x)as.integer(x[[1]])))+length(z(b,"//tr[@class='comment']",v))}
b=h(paste0(c,"/questions/20277"))
x=f(b)
u=unique(s(z(b,"//div[@class='pager-answers']/a",a),`[`,1)) #Grab all URLS of pages
if(length(u))x=x+sum(s(u,function(x)f(h(paste0(c,x)),-1))) #Apply comment computation of all URLs
y=gsub("[^0-9]","",z(b,"//div[@id='answers-header']/div/h2",v)[[1]])
cat("A",y,"C",x,sep="")
```

Tried on [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code) and outputted: `A125C499`.

Comment: +1 for using R, clear underdog but beautiful language :)

Answer (score 5):

### PHP which actually works (302 chars)

Unlike all of the other answers so far, this returns the correct answer even when the question spills onto more than one page.

```
<?function g($a,$b,$i){return json_decode(gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/$a/$i/$b?site=codegolf"),10,-8)))->items;}$i=array(20277);foreach(g("questions","answers",20277)as$x)$i[]=$x->answer_id;echo"A".(count($i)-1)."C".count(g("posts","comments",implode(";",$i)));
```

Comment: Your number of comments it correct but at the moment there are only 5 answers but you script says there are 6. Is it counting the question?

Comment: @FelixEve, I think it's probably counting the deleted answer. `(count($i)-1)` corrects the count to not include the question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor How can the script see the deleted answer? It should only be in the markup if logged in with a user that has privilege.

Comment: from PHP 5.4 you can use `[]` instead of `array()` to initialize

Comment: This one won't actually work if there the joined `$i` has over 100 items. (My own version of [the same in ruby](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20332/13815) doesn't have this limitation. Though admittedly it may bump into API limits. ;-) )

Comment: @Cruncher, API results are cached quite heavily - might be why?

Comment: @Denis, valid point.

Comment: @Cruncher: `count($i)-1` was needed because the array also contains the question_id.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby 175 (counts across pages, using the API instead of the DOM)

```
require'open-uri';require'json'
q=JSON.parse(open("http://qr.net/oyJn").read)["items"][0];a=q["answers"]
puts"A#{a.count}C#{[q,*a].reduce(0){|m,o|m+o["comments"].to_a.count}}"
```

That's 242 without the shortened url:

```
require'open-uri';require'json'
q=JSON.parse(open("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277?site=codegolf&filter=!azbR89z2Zw*dg.").read)["items"][0]
a=q["answers"]
puts"A#{a.count}C#{[q,*a].reduce(0){|m,o|m+o["comments"].to_a.count}}"
```

Previous 291 answer:

```
require'open-uri';require'json'
def g(o,l,f);JSON.parse(open("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/#{o}/#{l}/#{f}?site=codegolf").read)["items"];end
q=20277
p=g("questions",q,"answers").inject([q]){|m,o|m<<o["answer_id"]}
puts"A#{p.count-1}C#{p.map{|i|g("posts",i,"comments").count}.reduce(:+)}"
```

Credits to Peter Tailor for the idea of using the API, and Charles for pointing towards a better API.

Comment: damnit, that was my idea!

Comment: Actually, your use of the filtered API was better. Doing the same here shaves almost 120 characters off of my original answer. :-)

Answer (score 5):

### HTML, 37

*Sorry, Blatant rule abuse follows!*

```html
<script src=http://q0x.eu/1></script>
```

#### Explanation

`q0x.eu/1` redirects to: [http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277/comments?site=codegolf&callback=...](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277/comments?site=codegolf&callback=%28function%28d%29%7Bc=d.items.length;document.write%28%27%3Cscript%20src=%22http://q0x.eu/2%22%3E%3C/script%3E%27%29%7D%29)

where the callback is:

```js
(function(d){
    c=d.items.length;
    document.write('<script src="http://q0x.eu/2"></script>')
})
```

`q0x.eu/2` redirects to [http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277/answers?site=codegolf&callback=...](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277/answers?site=codegolf&callback=%28function%28d%29%7Ba=0;g=%5B%5D;d.items.map%28function%28f%29%7Ba%2b%2b;g.push%28f.answer_id%29%7D%29;document.write%28%27%3Cscript%20src=%22http://q0x.eu/3?n=%27%2bg.pop%28%29%2b%27%22%3E%3C/script%3E%27%29%7D%29)

```js
(function(d){
    a=0;
    g=[];
    d.items.map(function(f){
        a++;
        g.push(f.answer_id)
    });
    document.write('<script src="http://q0x.eu/3?n='+g.pop()+'"></script>')
})
```

and `q0x.eu/3?n=...` redirects to [http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers/.../comments?site=codegolf&callback=...](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/answers/.../comments?site=codegolf&callback=%28function%28d%29%7Bc%2b=d.items.length;g.length?document.write%28%27%3Cscript%20src=%22http://q0x.eu/3?n=%27%2bg.pop%28%29%2b%27%22%3E%3C/script%3E%27%29%3aalert%28%27A%27%2ba%2b%27C%27%2bc%29%7D%29)

```js
(function(d){
    c+=d.items.length;
    g.length ? document.write('<script src="http://q0x.eu/3?n='+g.pop()+'"></script>') : alert('A'+a+'C'+c)
})
```

I was originally trying to do it legitimately and might still have a go, but this was fun nevertheless!

Comment: Well, why not **HTTP, 8 chars** `q0x.eu/1` then? PS: legitimate solutions can't beat Perl anyways ;-) (blatant challenge)

Comment: @Tomas, that would be cheating! ;) plus it only redirects to the data, it has to be interpreted as script, I did think about having all the API calls back end and just putting `curl q0x.eu/1` or something, but was too lazy...

Answer (score 4):

### Python with [stackpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stackpy) 160

**Implementation**

```
s=__import__("stackpy").Site("codegolf");q=s.questions(20277);a=q.answers
print"A%dC%d"%(len(a),sum(len(s.answers(e.id()).comments)for e in a)+len(q.comments))
```

**Output**

```
A13C60
```

**Note**

Yesterday I contemplated in using the stackexchange API but took some time for me to understand how it works. Today, I saw there were couple of answers on the same theme. To make my answer a bit different, I though of using an external library.

Also realize that other answers which relies on parsing  for patterns like

are likely to break at anytime soon, so a more definite answer is to rely on a robust method like this one.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP: <s>184</s> 172

```
<?$h=file_get_contents('http://qr.net/_9');preg_match_all('/<t.*nt="([0-9]*)/',$h,$c);echo 'A'.substr_count($h,'rcell">').'C'.(array_sum($c[1])+substr_count($h,'mment">'));
```

Explanation:

```
<? // short open tag
  $h = file_get_contents('http://qr.net/_9'); // store in $h the content of the shortened url of the page
  preg_match_all('/<t.*nt="([0-9]*)/', $h, $c); // find each "show/hide X more comments" and store the numbers in $c
  echo
    'A' // output A
    .substr_count($h,'rcell">') // output the count of the occurrences of 'rcell">' (short for '"answercell">')
    .'C' // output C
    .( 
      array_sum( $c[1] ) // output the sum of the collapsed comments found before
      + 
      substr_count( $h, 'mment">') // output the count of the occurrences of 'mment">' (short for '"comment">')
    );
```

*For the first time PHP beats other languages in golf-scripts :')*

---

**Some extra markup to this topic to avoid regex "cheats":**

[show **9999** more comments](http://goo.gl)

Comment: **123456** more pickles. rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell" rcell"

Comment: damn you, ok will fix it ._.

Comment: "for the first time PHP beats other languages in golf-scripts" It's true that it's rare, but [there've been a few](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=[code-golf]+php+isaccepted%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: Well, nt="99" ... your comment count seems to be wrong... :-P It is especially ironic that someone punishing regex cheaters is cheating as well :-)

Comment: should be fixed now :P

Comment: are you sure? :-)

Comment: no but I'm kinda bored of spend the life here to fix this stupid script :P

Answer (score 3):

Cannot believe that nobody has came up with it until now! Most direct solution to use :-)

## jQuery, <strike>116</strike> 101 chars (off competition)

Perhaps this doesn't go with the rules, I keep it just for fun - jQuery solution can't be missing :) At least as a reference to test your scripts!!! ;-)

Try running from the FireBug console:

```
$('.comments-link').click();
setTimeout("alert('A'+$('.answer').length+'C'+$('.comment').length)",999)
```

If you have slow connection, increase the timeout :-) Thanks @Fez Vrasta for the great idea of clicking the "show more" links!

---

Some other stuff to break solution of others, class="comment" and the timed bomb
[ha](http://bit.ly/answercell)
[ha](http://bit.ly/comment)

Comment: This will not work if the page is closed, like the question requires.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery performs poorly on closed pages :-) I guess it's out of competition then, but cannot really be missing! :)

Comment: I did that and my answer was deemed invalid. I deleted it.

Comment: @Victor, why not keep it just for fun? How many chars did you have?

Comment: @Tomas. Ok, I undeleted it.

Answer (score 3):

### R 239

```
library(XML);F=function(x,y,f=length,z='')sum(as.double(xpathSApply(htmlParse('http://qr.net/1_'),sprintf('//%s[@class="%s"]%s',x,y,z),f)));cat("A",F("div","answer"),"C",F("a","comments-link ",xmlValue,"//b")+F("td","comment-text"),sep="")
```

After I posted my answer, the output is:

```
A13C60
```

Comment: `F("div","answer")` and `F("td","comment-text")` doesn't work for me (`Error in F("div", "answer") : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`). Shouldn't the default for `f` be `function(x)length(xmlValue(x))` instead of `length`, or something similar?

Comment: It works for me... `xpathSApply(...,length)` should return a vector, not a list. I am not sure why you would get a list. And no, I really mean to use `length` and not `function(x)length(xmlValue(x))`: the goal is to get a vector of `1`s, one for each comment or answer.

Comment: ok turns out the fact that `xpathSApply` can takes other functions (like `length`)  than `xmlValue` and similar ones is a novelty from version 3.94 of the package (if I understand correctly their changelog). That may be why it didn't work for me. Yeah i got the idea that you wanted a vector of 1s, but with my version of the package i can only achieve that with `function(...` instead of just `length`.

Answer (score 2):

### Node, 403

```
r=require;m='comments'
r('http').get("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/20277?site=codegolf&filter=!azbR89z2Zw*dg.").on('response',function(p){p.pipe(r('zlib').createGunzip(o="")).on('readable',function(){o+=this.read()}).on('end',function(){d=JSON.parse(o).items[0]
r('util').print("A",d.answer_count,"C",(d[m].length+d.answers.reduce(function(p,c){return p+(c[m]?c[m].length:0)},0)))})})
```

Only hits the API once... can likely be shortened, but I'm new to Node.

Answer (score 2):

### <strike>153</strike> <strike>151</strike> 147, C# & CsQuery

C# With CsQuery:

```
    var d = CsQuery.CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://qr.net/1_");
    Console.Write("A" + d[".answer"].Count() + "C" + d[".comment"].Count());
```

Full program:

```
class P{static void Main(){var d =CsQuery.CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://qr.net/1_");Console.Write("A"+d[".answer"].Count()+"C"+d[".comment"].Count());}}
```

#### 118 C# & CsQuery in LINQPad or in Roslyn

If running through LINQPad is allowed then:

```
var d =CsQuery.CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://qr.net/1_");Console.Write("A"+d[".answer"].Count()+"C"+d[".comment"].Count());
```

Produces:

> A14C48

Some more fun.

#### F# with CsQuery, 143:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main x= 
 let d=CsQuery.CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://qr.net/1_")
 printfn "A%dC%d" d.[".answer"].Length d.[".comment"].Length
 0
```